# One git repository, but one file is different on two different computers

Tags: git, command-line

I have one remote (off-site, hosted) git repository that I am accessing from two laptops.  Since I am the only one using this repository, I do not bother to have separate branches.  Usually when I commit and push to the repository, I will soon after fetch and merge on my other laptop.

I now find myself in a situation where I have a different version of one file on both computers, and git tells me that nothing needs to be done and there are no updates to be made.

On both laptops, when I type

```
git remote -v
```

I have receive exactly the same thing - the address of the remote repository

```
origin  git@XYZ.com:myproj.git (fetch)
origin  git@XYZ.com:myproj.git (push)
```

On both laptops a git status call returns:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
```

If I execute

```
git remote update
```

I receive

```
Fetching origin
```

and then I call

```
git status -uno
```

and I get

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit
```

Finally, if I call

```
git fetch origin
```

there is no output. And if I then call

```
git merge
```

I get the response

```
Already up-to-date.
```

When I type

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

on both laptops, I receive exactly the same hash value:

```
d353340c1.....8503b
```

As far as I can tell, both laptops think that everything is current with the remote repository, but one of the files is clearly different on the two laptops.

How can this be, and how to I get to state where everything is truly sync'd?

One laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04 with git version 2.7.4 from the command line.
The other is Windows 10, accessed via git bash 2.19.0.windows.1 on a Mintty terminal.

Comment: have you tried `git merge FETCH_HEAD`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git rev-parse HEAD` on both systems?

Comment: @bk2204, my post has been edited to add that.

Comment: How is it different?  Have you determined it by inspection or by a hash of it?  Is the file actually in the repository, or is it ignored (you can use `git check-ignore` to find out)?

Comment: The files are different by inspection (there are 4 additional lines in one of the versions). This is also clearly reflected in a size difference in bytes (several hundred) reported by each OS.  There is no .gitignore file anywhere in the repository, and when I type git check-ignore with the file name, it returns nothing.

Comment: @Serge, the `get merge FETCH_HEAD` command results in `Already up-to-date.` on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Everything *except* the difference in two checked-out files seems perfectly normal, here.  Given that these two checked-out files are (apparently—see below) tracked files, i.e., in Git's index on each machine, that kind of difference generally *should* result in `git status` saying that there are changes `not staged for commit` on at least one of the two systems.

There are, at this point, several things that could be going on:

1. The file might actually *not* be in the index *and* be ignored (but this seems to have been ruled out in the comments).
2. The file might be mis-marked "clean" in the cache, so that `git status` just *assumes* that the working tree copy of the file matches the index copy of the file.
3. The file might literally be "clean".

Before I go into detail on cases 2 and 3, it's worth noting a peculiar fact here.  The files that you see and work with, when you work with Git, are *not in Git*.  The files that *are* in Git—are stored inside a commit—are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form, that only Git can actually *use*.  Hence, in order to use a commit, Git has to *copy* that commit out somewhere, turning the files into ordinary everday files that you can actually use.  These files are in your *working tree* or *work-tree* and this work area is not actually *in* the Git repository.  (The repository proper is generally in the `.git` subdirectory in the top level of your working tree.)

Now, case 1 is pretty simple:

- Git's index itself is a complicated beastie but it amounts to a list of all your files-to-be-committed, including the already-Git-ified *contents* they should have as of the *next* commit.
- A file that *isn't* in Git's index is not going to be in the next commit (though of course you can change this, using `git add` for instance).
- A file that exists in your working tree, but not in Git's index, is by definition an *untracked file*.

That's all there is to being untracked: it just has to exist in your working tree, yet not exist in Git's index.  Untracked files normally cause Git to whine, but if listed in a `.gitignore`, Git stops whining.  This of course requires the existence of `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` files.  (You can have a global `.gitignore` in your home directory configuration, but `git check-ignore -v` will point it out, if it's causing a file to be ignored.)

Case 3 can happen if there are *clean* and *smudge* filters defined for this repository (via `.gitattributes` in the repository, and filter definitions in some Git configuration file(s)):

- The smudge filter, if there is one, is responsible for *changing* the file as it comes out of Git.  When Git extracts a commit, it first copies all of the commit's files into its index (so that they're ready to go into the next commit).<sup>1</sup>  Then, Git extracts those files—de-compressing and de-Git-ifying them—into versions you can actually use, which go into your work-tree.  If there is a smudge filter, *the data pass through the smudge filter on the way to the work-tree copy* so the work-tree copy need not match the (expanded-out) index copy.
- The clean filter, if there is one, is responsible for *changing* the file as it goes into Git.  When you `git add` a file, Git compresses, Git-ifies, and de-duplicates the file's data.  If there is a clean filter, Git runs the data through the clean filter before it begins the compression and Git-ization process.  So the clean filter can *take away* stuff that the smudge filter *put in*.  In this way, you can commit files that are different from the files you actually use.<sup>2</sup>

Depending on the clean and smudge filters in use, it's conceivable that most of the content of some work-tree file would be entirely different on two different machines.  This does of course require that the file have clean and smudge filters defined, which in turn requires `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` files.

This leaves one last possibility: case 2, where Git *thinks* the file is clean (because it's marked that way) even though it's not.  The easiest way to defeat this is to `touch` the file (using the Unix/Linux `touch`  command, if you have it).  That sets the modification timestamp on the file to "now", which is presumably later than any saved modification timestamp (from "then", some seconds or more ago) saved in Git's index.

If none of these work to find or correct the issue, something else—something very mysterious and possibly a Git bug—is going on.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is oversimplified: there are some cases where there's already something in Git's index and it can be left in place.  We'll ignore these corner cases here.

<sup>2</sup>This is, at least in theory, a way to get something people keep asking for: to have a configuration file with a "local configuration" section that does not get committed.  There are some difficult implementation issues with doing this, though.